# Set the options for the Field of Type Radio button in Form Helper in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using a Form helper in CakePHP. like

```
   echo $form->input('field', array(
    'type' => 'radio','legend'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],
  // 'after' => '--after--',
    // 'between' => '--between---',
    'separator' => '--separator--',
   'options' => array('1', '2') 
  ));
```

which generates me as

```
<div class="input radio">
 <fieldset>
    <legend>Gender</legend>

     <input type="hidden" value="" id="field_" name="data[field]"/>
     <input type="radio" value="0" id="Field0" name="data[field]"/>
     <label for="Field0">1</label>--separator--
     <input type="radio" value="1" id="Field1" name="data[field]"/>
   <label for="Field1">2</label>

 </fieldset>
</div>
```

Is there any way to keep my options that i have received from my Database instead of 1,2

where i tried it with receving my options using

```
   <?php foreach ($viewfields as $r): ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(document).ready(function($){


         $("#"+<?=$r['Attribute']['id'];?>).each(function() { 
          type= "<?=$r['Attribute']['type'];?>";

           if(type=="radio")
              {
                   var ht = $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost/FormBuilder/index.php/forms/viewChoices/"+attribute_id,
                  async: false
                          }).responseText;

              var myObject = eval('(' + ht + ')');

             var data = myObject;var j=0;

 $.map(data.choices, function(i){ j++; 
   alert(i.choice);//which alerts as male and female correctly.
  return i.choice;});  
             }


        });//each

      });
```

alert(i.choice); alerts the options correctly ..

How to keep these options in the array() of the Form Helper so that to get these options male and female instead of default 1,2

Please suggest me..

Answer (score 2):

Place the options in a key => value array - as shown here : [Cake Options](http://book.cakephp.org/view/192/options-options)

```
echo $form->input('field', array(
  'type' => 'radio',
  'legend' => $r['Attribute']['label'],
  'separator' => '--separator--',
  'options' => array('Male' => 'male', 'Female' => 'female') 
));
```

See how you go.